# CakePHP, mod_rewrite and SVN

Tags: apache, svn, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a very strange problem.

I configured an empty `cakephp 2.3` project, I made all the cakephp changes (`database.php`, `salt`, etc.) and the `debugkit` too.

Everything worked fine and I got the default page of the cake without an error.

When I committed this project to the `svn` and then I checkout the project I received the error that the `mod_rewrite is not configured properly`.

Why? What is the difference? How can i check it?

(Notes: I changed the user owner to be the same on both folders, I set the permissions to 777, I have not changed the httpd conf so in both cases is the same, and also the vhost for both projects are the same, only the server's name and  path is different.)

Comment: Well, if the servers 'name' is different, then it is a different http server, virtual or physical. So that servers configuration might very well differ from the prior one. It aparently does, the error message definately has nothing to do with svn.

Comment: Reading your last passage again I wonder: how can the "server's name" be different whilst you claim at the same time that it is the same vhost?

Comment: Try to change the permission into 755 since some servers are having problems when permission is 777.

Comment: With server's name i mean the property in vhost file, in both cases the server is my development machine.

Comment: i tried it with exactly the same vhosts (i changed the folders' name, to check it, again the same situation)
on the checked out project i receive this error on apache log 
[Sun Mar 03 11:44:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/dimitris/PHP Projects/webrealtor.gr/trunk/debug_kit, referer: http://www.webrealtor/

Comment: Stupid error. I used the eclipse commit and i don't know the reason but it didn't commit the .htaccess file of trunk folder. (after a diff i found that the files .htaccess and .travis.yml are not commited)

I copied it from the project which worked and pasted it in the other folder and worked!

Thank you for your answers!!!

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer so that it can be marked 'answered' or remove the question